# how can lock or block some SIM carrier on android 4.1.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sim-card, sim-unlocking

have here in my country to types of SIM cards on the carriers, the first is open to the all networks... internet, sms, calls... and a second is all close  data , only to call

how can i do to close in a android 4.1.2 on a samsung  gt s6310 to by only read a second SIM card and block the first?

thanks !!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you handing the phone to someone else  and don't want him to access data at all?

Comment: no here the religios people dont want internet in their phone, but some ones want phones android. here exist to types of SIM the the first is the common in all services an the second is without all services only calling.

Comment: how to can do block the reception of the firs types of SIM on the phone. thanks